# Bootstrap é CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, aplicação-web, visual-studio

Meu professor disse que no trabalho dele toda a estetização do site deverá ser feita em CSS, uma pergunta: Posso fazer em Bootstrap?

Comment: Tem algumas [informações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/twitter-bootstrap/info) sobre o bootstrap na tag

Comment: O Bootstrap é composto de instruções com `javascript` e `css`! O mais correto é você direcionar essa pergunta a seu professor, mas presumo que o objetivo dele seja a construção de algo sem a utilização de um `framework`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode sim, o Bootstrap é um *framework* desenvolvido em CSS puro. Não existe contraindicações neste caso, ele faz uso de certos elementos HTML e propriedades CSS que requerem o uso do HTML5 *Doctype*. Inclua-o no início de todos os seus projetos.

Se achar que ainda assim seu professor pode ser contra o uso, você pode extrair do Bootstrap os estilos que deseja usar e jogar em um arquivo .css criado por você, ai certamente ele não terá argumentos.

Para mais detalhes:
http://getbootstrap.com.br/css/

Comment: Cuidado que se ele quer a estilização FEITA em CSS não há de querer um estilização já pronta e deverá ser uma criada por si, presumo eu.

Comment: é uma possibilidade.

Answer (score 0):

Mais ou menos, bootstrap é um Framework CSS, porem, ele utiliza de jQuery em interações, veja o exemplo a seguir:

***Com um arquivo JS***

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Outra ação</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Algo mais aqui</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link separado</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***Sem o arquivo JS***

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Ação</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Outra ação</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Algo mais aqui</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link separado</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

***Finalizando***

Repare que o resultado obtido não é o mesmo, porem pormanece sendo CSSm, agora averigue se seu professor permite usar JavaScript, se sim pode usar tranquilamente se não, procure outras bibliotecas ou use como base o Bootstrap CSS para faze ralgo parecido.